# Trazer múltiplos valores de um join no mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, framework

Galera, tenho uma dúvida sobre uma consulta mysql usando o Framework Codeigniter.
Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

Tabela Produtos

```
|--------|-----------------|
|  id    |   nome_produto  |
|--------|-----------------|
|   1    |   Camisa Tal    |
|--------|-----------------|
|   2    |   Bermuda Tal   |
|--------|-----------------|
```

Tabela Produtos - Grade

```
|--------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|  id    |     tamanho     |   valor_item    |   produto_id    |
|--------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|   1    |        P        |      35,00      |        1        |
|--------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|   2    |        M        |      45,00      |        1        |
|--------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|   3    |        P        |      22,00      |        2        |
|--------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
```

Preciso que na consulta, ao visualizar o produto, tenha uma como exibir todos os valores do tamanho dos produtos. Exemplo:

Selecionei o produto 1, nesse mesmo produto temos duas variações de tamanho mas com preços diferentes, preciso trazer esses preços diferente para dentro do resultado da visualização do produtos.

O minha consulta está assim:

```
public function detalhe($id)
    {
        $this->db->select("prod.*");
        $this->db->select("gr.valor_item");
        $this->db->where('prod.slug', $id);
        $this->db->join('ga845_produtos_grades gr', 'prod.id = gr.produtos_id', "inner");
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get('ga845_view_produtos prod');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Dessa forma atual, ao invés da consulta trazer todos os valores, por exemplo do produto Camisa, ele traz apenas o primeiro valor que seria de R$ 35,00 ignorando o de 45,00. Como eu resolvo isso?

Obrigado e espero ter explicado bem a dificuldade.

Comment: Você está limitando a consulta para retornar apenas uma linha: `$this->db->limit(1)`, por isso não aparece o segundo valor... Não seria por isso?

Comment: Infelizmente não @Zulian já tentei apenas removendo mas o resultado da consulta continua o mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Segue exemplo:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE produtos_temp ( id int, descricao varchar(100) );
INSERT INTO produtos_temp VALUES( 1, "Camisa Tal" );
INSERT INTO produtos_temp VALUES( 2, "Bermuda Tal" );
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE grade_temp ( id int, tamanho char(1), valor double(10,2), produtos_temp_id int);
INSERT INTO grade_temp VALUES( 1, "P", 35.77, 1 );
INSERT INTO grade_temp VALUES( 2, "M", 25.50, 1 );
INSERT INTO grade_temp VALUES( 3, "G", 49.90, 1 );
INSERT INTO grade_temp VALUES( 4, "P", 25.00, 2 );
INSERT INTO grade_temp VALUES( 5, "M", 35.50, 2 );
INSERT INTO grade_temp VALUES( 6, "G", 59.90, 2 );

SELECT 
    pt.id as ID,
    pt.descricao as Descricao,
    SUM(TamanhoP) AS P,
    SUM(TamanhoM) AS M,
    SUM(TamanhoG) AS G
FROM
    produtos_temp AS pt
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        IF(tamanho = 'P', valor, 0) AS TamanhoP,
        IF(tamanho = 'M', valor, 0) AS TamanhoM,
        IF(tamanho = 'G', valor, 0) AS TamanhoG,
        produtos_temp_id as ID
    FROM
        grade_temp
    WHERE
        produtos_temp_id = :produtos_temp_id
    GROUP BY tamanho WITH ROLLUP) AS gt ON pt.id = gt.ID;
```

No *doctrine*, por ser uma consulta um pouco mais complexa, você pode utilizar o [ResultSetMapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/Doctrine/ORM/Query/ResultSetMapping.html), dessa forma para capturar o retorno:

```
$sqlFile = new \SplFileObject('caminho para o aarquivo .sql');
$sql =  $sqlFile->openFile()->fread($sqlFile->getSize());

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addScalarResult('ID', 'ID');
$rsm->addScalarResult('Descricao', 'Descricao');
$rsm->addScalarResult('P', 'P');
$rsm->addScalarResult('M', 'M');
$rsm->addScalarResult('G', 'G');

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$query->setParameter(':produtos_temp_id', $data['produtos_temp_id']);

return $query->getResult();
```