# Como retornar uma coleção de dados usando Doctrine ResultSetMapping?

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-7, doctrine-2

Tenho o seguinte script que encontra-se funcional:

```
SELECT
    r.coluna_1 as Coluna_1,
    e.coluna_1 as Coluna_2,
FROM produto r
INNER JOIN empresa e ON r.id_empresa = e.id_empresa
WHERE  r.id_tipo = 'N'
    AND r.data_devolucao <= :dataDevolucao
    AND e.id_empresa IS NOT NULL
    AND e.id_empresa = :empresa
    AND (select count(*) from produto_nota rn
                               where rn.id_nota_tipo = 14
                               and id_reserva = r.id_reserva) = 0

GROUP BY r.id_produto
```

Andei olhando uns exemplos de como utilizar `[Doctrine ResultSetMapping][1]`, mas devido meu baixo conhecimento em relação ao doctrine ainda não obtive sucesso.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o seu caso, pode utilizar [addScalarResult](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/Doctrine/ORM/Query/ResultSetMapping.html#method_addScalarResult) **para mapear cada colunas do retorno do script**.

É muito simples. Recentemente respondi uma pergunta que pode te ajudar, [bem aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328924/trazer-m%C3%BAltiplos-valores-de-um-join-no-mysql/329039#329039).

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
$sqlFile = new \SplFileObject('caminho para o seu arquivo .sql');
$sql =  $sqlFile->openFile()->fread($sqlFile->getSize());

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addScalarResult('Coluna_1', 'Coluna_1');
$rsm->addScalarResult('Coluna_2', 'Coluna_1');
$rsm->addScalarResult('Coluna_3', 'Coluna_3'); // uma para cada, lembre-se!

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$query->setParameter(':dataDevolucao', $data['dataDevolucao']);
$query->setParameter(':empresa', $data['empresa']);

var_dump($query->getResult());
```

Comment: deu certo. Obrigado.